# Narrow and save results in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a large MS Access database, and I want to get rid of all the records that aren't relevant to my city.  I could make a series of queries, but that would be tedious.  And I don't know an efficient way to get just the data from the queries into another database, or into Excel.  I only know tedious ways.

Comment: Explain some of the tedious methods you think of. Maybe then we will see if we could better it. Or the answer and discussion could be broad.

Comment: I could make a query for each table.  But I have eight such large databases, and each database has about two dozen tables.

Comment: Lacks detail and is too broad to comment ! Downvoted.

Comment: I ended up streamlining a tedious method as much as possible.  I did it on a weekend when I had a bad cold and didn't have much brain to begin with.  I hope I never have to do that again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to tedious queries, you can write tedious VBA code.

Loop the recordset and validate each record. If it fails, delete the record and move to the next. 
Even though tedious, it is more fun than writing SQL.